405 Method Not Allowed on [specific endpoint] in .NET 8 Web API
I am encountering a strange problem.
In our application I have a single controller where PUT, DELETE, POST getting 405 error
while the rest of controllers are working properly.
here is how my Web.Config is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            <remove name="WebDAV"/>
        </handlers>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
        </modules>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" 
                    arguments=".\WebUI.dll" 
                    stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
                    stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
                    hostingModel="inprocess" />
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <clear />
                <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers " value="*"/>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
                <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: B10BA5B4-B02C-4528-9272-8478A9F7B038-->


Here is my startup.cs

// configure services
        #region CORS

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
                AllowedOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
        });

        #endregion

// under configure
    app.UseCors(AllowedOrigins);


From controller I am getting this Response header:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *
Allow: GET, HEAD
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store
Date: Thu, 07 Nov 2024 09:44:21 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Controller:
using Application.Common.DTO;
using Application.TableObjects;
using Application.TableObjects.Commands;
using Application.TableObjects.Queries;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RI.QueryExecutor;

namespace WebUI.Controllers;

public class ListTableController : ApiControllerBase
{
    public ListTableController(ISender sender, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(sender, httpContextAccessor) { }

    [HttpPost("save")]
    public async Task<IResult<TableIndexDto>> CreateAsyc([FromBody] CreateTableIndex request)
        => await Mediator.Send(request);

    [HttpDelete("save")]
    public async Task<IResult<TableIndexDto>> UpdateAsyc([FromQuery] DeleteTableIndex request)
        => await Mediator.Send(request);

    [HttpPut("save")]
    public async Task<IResult<TableIndexDto>> UpdateAsyc([FromBody] UpdateTableIndex request)
        => await Mediator.Send(request);
}

angular service:
post<TPost, TOut>(url: string, param: TPost): Observable<TOut> {
    return this
      .http
      .post<TOut>(url, param, this.buildHttpOptions())
      .pipe(catchError(_ => this.handleError(_)));
  }



  private buildHttpOptions(): { headers: HttpHeaders; } {
    return {
      headers: this.buildBaseHeaders()
    };
  }

  private buildBaseHeaders(): HttpHeaders {
    const lang: string = 'it';
    const user:string = STRING_EMPTY;
    const datow: string = STRING_EMPTY;
    return new HttpHeaders(this.GetHttpHeaderObject(user, lang, datow));
  }




  private GetHttpHeaderObject(user: string, lang: string, datow: string) : any {
    return {
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
      'Pragma': 'no-cache',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept-Language': `${lang}-${lang.toUpperCase()}`
    }
  }


Can you post the controller code and how you are calling it

Same error using swagger UI or postman

Set the code in web.config file. i know you have set it but make runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to false as well:
<system. Webserver>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>

Instead of removing from the site I would like to suggest you to uninstall the WebDAVModule  from the iis feature list.

Make sure in the site request filtering setting is like this:

Add required verbs in the request filtering as shown below one by one:

In Http response header set the name and value as shown below(mention the methos instead of setting *):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept


Still getting error 405.

@whebz could you share your header. You can collect the details by using the fiddler tool. also share your updated web.config file. also, could you share your working controller code?

You have duplicate method names for DELETE and UPDATE. I suggest that you change your method names so that they do not rely on reflection to determine the incoming object type, which will surely cause issues:
[HttpDelete("save")]
    public async Task<IResult<TableIndexDto>> DeleteAsync([FromQuery] DeleteTableIndex request)
        => await Mediator.Send(request);

    [HttpPut("save")]
    public async Task<IResult<TableIndexDto>> UpdateAsync([FromBody] UpdateTableIndex request)
        => await Mediator.Send(request);

As a sidenote, you have a typo in all of your method names. It's "async" and not "asyc".

Still not working.

Just to eliminate all options I can think of, can you try and change the endpoints routes to something different each time? That is, [HttpDelete("delete")], [HttpPut("update")], [HttpPost("save")] for example? This shouldn't be an issue, but it's a simple thing to try.

I am now getting same problem in other apps hosted in IIS. some post endpoint different controllers are getting 405 error. using docker container or kestrel working fine
